# Three sides of a triangle- find general law (polya)

Tags: induction, triangles

The tree sides of a triangle are of lengths $l$, $m$, and $n$, respectively. The numbers $l, m,$ and $n$  are positive integers.

$l \le m \le n$

Find the number of different triangles of the described kind for a given 'n'. ( Take $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  n)$
 **Find a general law governing the dependence of the number of triangles on $n$.**
*from Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning .*
what i find is :
if i write the three sequence
1- n . (n)
2-number of all possibilities of l and m for each n .(P)
3- number of possible triangle that we can construct according to triangle    iniquity. (T) 
is 
$p = (1,2,6,10,15,21,28,26,45,55,...)$
$T=  (1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,42,...)$
$n= (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)$
some observation about these sequence
1- for $P$ :
* it's  increasing by n
*$P_n$  - $T_n-1$ = $T_n$
 such that $P_n$ = (number of possible values for l and m for such n )
$T_n$ = number of possible triangles for n
2- For $T$ 
$1,1+1,2+2,2+2+2,2+2+2+3,2+2+2+3+3,2+2+2+3+3+4,2+2+2+3+3+4+4,2+2+2+3+3+4+4+5,2+2+2+3+3+4+4+5+5,...$
How can i derive general law ??

Comment: Hint: The triangle inequality states that $l+m>n$.  If $m$ and $n$ are fixed, what are the possible values for $l$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, for $l,m,n$ to make a triangle, $l+m>n$.

Fix $n$ and $m$, then we know that $n+1-m\leq l\leq m$.  If $n+1-m\leq m$, then $\frac{n+1}{2}\leq m$ and these restrictions are not empty.

In such a case, there are $m-(n+1-m)+1=2m-n$ possible values for $l$.  Now, we have two cases:

- If $n$ is odd, then $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is a natural number, so we need:
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{m=\frac{n+1}{2}}^n(2m-n)&=2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-2\left(\frac{\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}}{2}\right)-n\left(n-\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\\
  &=n(n+1)-\frac{1}{4}(n^2-1)-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\\
  &=(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{1}{4}(n-1)\right)\\
  &=\frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2
  \end{align*}
- If $n$ is odd, then $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is not a natural number, so $\frac{n+1}{2}\leq m$ reduces to $\frac{n}{2}+1\leq m$.  I'll leave the rest of the derivation as an exercise at this point.

Comment: I undestood everything except for the part where you find the values for $l$. How do you infer that there are $2m-n$ possible values for $l$ ?.

Comment: @Shew You know that $n+1-m\leq l\leq m$ and $l$ is an integer, so this is just the count for the number of integers between the two numbers.  You have to add one because the endpoints are included.